# Mediapipe Display Body Landmarks Only

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, mediapipe

I have installed Mediapipe (0.9.0.1) using Python (3.7.0) on windows 11.
I have been able to successfully get Mediapipe to generate landmarks (for face and body); for an image, video, and webcam stream.

I would like to now get Mediapipe to **only** draw body specific landmarks (i.e. exclude facial landmarks).

I understand that I may use OpenCV (or Czone) to accomplish this goal, however, I am looking to achieve my objective using Mediapipe (i.e. using the `draw_landmarks` function in the MediaPipe library).

The specific bit of code I am trying (but with errors) is the following:

```
#Initialize a list to store the detected landmarks.
    landmarks = []

    # Iterate over the Mediapipe detected landmarks.
    for landmark in results.pose_landmarks.landmark:
        
        # Append the Mediapipe landmark into the list.
        landmarks.append((int(landmark.x * width), int(landmark.y * height),
                                (landmark.z * width)))
    
    #create index list for specific landmarks 
    body_landmark_indices = [11,12,13,14,15,16,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32]

    landmark_list_body = []

    #Create a list which only has the required landmarks
    for index in body_landmark_indices:
        landmark_list_body.append(landmarks[index - 1])

    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                        image=output_image,
                        landmark_list=landmark_list_body.pose_landmarks,
                        connections=mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                        landmark_drawing_spec=landmark_drawing_spec,
                        connection_drawing_spec=connection_drawing_spec)`

Executing the above I get the error `'list' object has no attribute 'pose_landmarks'
```

I have replaced `landmark_list=landmark_list_body.pose_landmarks,` with `landmark_list=landmark_list_body` but with errors.

I am now very tiered and out of ideas. Is there a capeless hero out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone please provide some suggestions? Are there more details I can share which may help? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
from mediapipe.python.solutions.pose import PoseLandmark
from mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils import DrawingSpec
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose


custom_style = mp_drawing_styles.get_default_pose_landmarks_style()
custom_connections = list(mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)

# list of landmarks to exclude from the drawing
excluded_landmarks = [
    PoseLandmark.LEFT_EYE, 
    PoseLandmark.RIGHT_EYE, 
    PoseLandmark.LEFT_EYE_INNER, 
    PoseLandmark.RIGHT_EYE_INNER, 
    PoseLandmark.LEFT_EAR,
    PoseLandmark.RIGHT_EAR,
    PoseLandmark.LEFT_EYE_OUTER,
    PoseLandmark.RIGHT_EYE_OUTER,
    PoseLandmark.NOSE,
    PoseLandmark.MOUTH_LEFT,
    PoseLandmark.MOUTH_RIGHT ]

for landmark in excluded_landmarks:
    # we change the way the excluded landmarks are drawn
    custom_style[landmark] = DrawingSpec(color=(255,255,0), thickness=None) 
    # we remove all connections which contain these landmarks
    custom_connections = [connection_tuple for connection_tuple in custom_connections 
                            if landmark.value not in connection_tuple]


IMAGE_FILES = ["test.jpg"]
BG_COLOR = (192, 192, 192) 
with mp_pose.Pose(
    static_image_mode=True,
    model_complexity=2,
    enable_segmentation=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5) as pose:
    for idx, file in enumerate(IMAGE_FILES):
        image = cv2.imread(file)
        image_height, image_width, _ = image.shape
        results = pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        annotated_image = image.copy()

        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
            annotated_image,
            results.pose_landmarks,
            connections = custom_connections, #  passing the modified connections list
            landmark_drawing_spec=custom_style) # and drawing style 

        cv2.imshow('landmarks', annotated_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It modifies the `DrawingSpec` and `POSE_CONNECTIONS` to "hide" a subset of landmarks.
However, due to the way the `draw_landmarks()` function is implemented in Mediapipe, it is also required to add a condition in `drawing_utils.py` (located in `site-packages/mediapipe/python/solutions`):

```
if drawing_spec.thickness == None: continue
```

Add it before Line 188 (see [MediaPipe GitHub repo](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/3b66ac06230f30331db32e69a2ca0f1580f60551/mediapipe/python/solutions/drawing_utils.py#L188), `# White circle border`). The result should look like this:

```
...
      drawing_spec = landmark_drawing_spec[idx] if isinstance(
          landmark_drawing_spec, Mapping) else landmark_drawing_spec
      if drawing_spec.thickness == None: continue
      # White circle border
      circle_border_radius = max(drawing_spec.circle_radius + 1,
                                 int(drawing_spec.circle_radius * 1.2))
...
```

This change is required in order to completely eliminate the white border that is drawn around landmarks regardless of their drawing specification.

Hope it helps.

Comment: A simple acceptance of your answer is not enough. Your solution works perfectly and the steps provided were crystal clear. I see that [at this time] you have a limited number of contributions and therefore associated ranking/badges; but you are indeed someone who has a great amount to offer. I wish you all the best and thank you for the time and effort you spent to provide a solution. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the nice words, I've just decided to try to start answering questions :) Good luck and I'll be happy to try and help if you need to adapt the attached code for your task.