# Python Medipipe Holistic Draw Pose Arms Only

Tags: python, mediapipe

I'm currently building a program using Mediapipe Holistic in python. When drawing poses using Holistic I can't just draw on the arms (without the connection of the eyes, nose, mouth, body, etc.). I've looked in the documentation but found. Can anyone help? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils import DrawingSpec
from mediapipe.python.solutions.holistic import PoseLandmark
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands


custom_lm_styles = mp_drawing_styles.get_default_pose_landmarks_style()
custom_connections = list(mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS)

# list of landmarks to include on the image
included_landmarks = [
    # right hand set
    PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER, 
    PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW, 
    PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST, 

    # left hand set
    PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER, 
    PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW, 
    PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST, 
    #thumb, index and pinky are not required, since they are included in hand landmarks
     ]

def draw_hand(hand_landmarks):
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
            annotated_image,
            hand_landmarks,
            mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
            mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
            mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style())

def remove_landmark_connections(custom_connections, landmark):
    return filter(lambda con: is_landmark_in_connection(con, landmark), custom_connections)

def is_landmark_in_connection(connection, landmark):
    return landmark.value not in connection \
                  and not (PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER in connection and PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER in connection)
# remove the second condition if you want to have a connection between the shoulders

# obviously the custom_lm_styles can be cached, no need to do it at each frame if you are working with video
for landmark in custom_lm_styles:
    if landmark not in included_landmarks:
        # we change the way the excluded landmarks are drawn
        custom_lm_styles[landmark] = DrawingSpec(color=(255,255,0), thickness=None) 
        # we remove all connections which contain these landmarks
        custom_connections = remove_landmark_connections(custom_connections, landmark)


IMAGE_FILES = ["test.png"]
BG_COLOR = (192, 192, 192) # gray
with mp_holistic.Holistic(
    static_image_mode=True,
    model_complexity=2,
    enable_segmentation=True,
    refine_face_landmarks=True) as holistic:

    for idx, file in enumerate(IMAGE_FILES):
        image = cv2.imread(file)
        image_height, image_width, _ = image.shape

        # Convert the BGR image to RGB before processing.
        results = holistic.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

        # segmentation
        annotated_image = image.copy()
        condition = np.stack((results.segmentation_mask,) * 3, axis=-1) > 0.1
        bg_image = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        bg_image[:] = BG_COLOR
        annotated_image = np.where(condition, annotated_image, bg_image)
        
        # face mesh is not drawn

        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
            annotated_image,
            results.pose_landmarks,
            custom_connections,
            landmark_drawing_spec=custom_lm_styles)
        
        draw_hand(results.right_hand_landmarks)
        draw_hand(results.left_hand_landmarks)

        cv2.imshow('landmarks', annotated_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It modifies the `DrawingSpec` and `POSE_CONNECTIONS` to "hide" a subset of landmarks.
However, due to the way the `draw_landmarks()` function is implemented in Mediapipe, it is also required to add a condition in `drawing_utils.py` (located in `site-packages/mediapipe/python/solutions`):

```
if drawing_spec.thickness == None: continue
```

Add it before Line 188 (see [MediaPipe GitHub repo](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/3b66ac06230f30331db32e69a2ca0f1580f60551/mediapipe/python/solutions/drawing_utils.py#L188), `# White circle border`). The result should look like this:

```
...
      drawing_spec = landmark_drawing_spec[idx] if isinstance(
          landmark_drawing_spec, Mapping) else landmark_drawing_spec
      if drawing_spec.thickness == None: continue
      # White circle border
      circle_border_radius = max(drawing_spec.circle_radius + 1,
                                 int(drawing_spec.circle_radius * 1.2))
...
```

This change is required in order to completely eliminate the white border that is drawn around landmarks regardless of their drawing specification.

If you don't want to draw the hands you may comment the `draw_hand()` lines, but in this case it would make more sense for you to use MediaPipe Pose solution (you can take a look at example how to draw a subset of landmarks here: [Mediapipe Display Body Landmarks Only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75427369/10571624)).

The result should look like this:

[image: Arms and hands only]